# Formtastic Removing the numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have the following which works.

```
<%= semantic_form_for ([:admin,@client]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
  <label class="formlabel">Name</label>
  <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'text-input small-input'  }, :label => false, :hint => "Enter Company Name" %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

This Outputs the following

1 Name Text Field for input

and Save

How do i remove the "1" in Formtastic

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your `app/assets/stylesheets/client.css.scss`

```
.my_form ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

and then define your form with `:class => "my_form"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove these via CSS. Formtastic uses the list tag format to write out it's forms.

I know there is a gem if you use twitter-bootstrap, that will alter the way formtastic writes out the forms. But, editing the CSS is usually easy enough.

Comment: Thanks i thought much, however any ideas within css